# How to change z-index on li hover?

Tags: css, z-index, transform, scale

I have a `<ul>` containing `<li>` that have *images* in them. I want to have each image scale to a larger size on hover, as well as become opaque. However, on hover the image is covered by the next image when it becomes larger. I'm not sure if I'm putting the `z-index` in the correct places... Here's the css code that I have thus far:

```
.artgallery {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    height:80%;
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
}

.artgallery ul {
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.artgallery li {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:19%;
    opacity:.7;
    transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index:0;
}

.artgallery li:hover {
    opacity:1;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index:100;
}

.artgallery img {
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
}

.artgallery a {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<div class="artgallery">        
    <img src="images/art.png" style="width:66px;height:66px;position:absolute;top:2px;left:5px;z-index:2;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="art/22.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/22_thumb.jpg"></a> </li>
        <li><a href="art/21.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/21_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/20.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/20_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/19.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/19_thumb.jpg"></a>   </li>
        <li><a href="art/18.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/18_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/17.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/17_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/16.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title="WIP"><img src="art/16_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/15.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/15_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/14.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/14_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/13.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/13_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/12.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title="WIP"><img src="art/12_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/11.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/11_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/10.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title="WIP"><img src="art/10_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/9.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/9_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/8.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/8_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/7.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/7_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/6.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/6_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/5.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/5_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/4.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/4_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/3.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title=" "><img src="art/3_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/2.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title="paint doodles"><img src="art/2_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="art/1.jpg" data-lightbox="art" title="circa 2007"><img src="art/1_thumb.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: __First things first:__ Don't just throw your whole code for this at us. Remove any unnecessary parts and make a http://jsfiddle.net demo, so we can test on our own. __Second:__ You should always use the unprefixed versions of transition etc. as the last ones. In your CSS the unprefixed version will be overwritten by the browser-specific version.

Comment: And __Third:__ The next time you edit your post, check for previous edits. I fixed your entire formatting so we can read a thing and you just removed it. Thank you.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, first time posting!

Comment: @priyanka good question and nice presentation for first post, no worries SO has seen much worse (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That CSS is ok, by the way you don't need to repeat transform properties on :hover pseudo-class :

```
.artgallery li:hover{
    opacity:1;        
    z-index:100;
}
```

You can also try to put on the hover element img a higher z-index (better safe than sorry) :

```
.artgallery li:hover img{
    position: relative;        
    z-index:200;
}
```

Comment: Wow this absolutely solved my problem! I feel so silly, spent an hour trying to figure this out and you solved it in less than 5 minutes ;) Thank you so much!!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to +1 :( But I marked it correct so hopefully that's fine

Comment: It's mostly for other people to know that you don't need more help :)